# Reviewing a website 

Tags: website-design, analytics

I'm looking for a tool (free/paid) like a program that help me in reviewing my website style and interface such as explain the content of the home page (footer, header ..... ) taking snapshots and write comment on them ... I know this can be done using (print screen) and the MS paint but I need a more professional tool to use.

Answer (score 2):

try Firefox addon named "Fireshot".

Comment: taking shots is not my problem i want a tool that help me in organize my work and add comments to the snapshots and highlight sections from a certain page

Comment: I think you didn't even try installing the addon, right? It allows you to take the snaphot, edit, add comments and highlights, then save to png or jpeg. Try first and then let me know if that is enough or if you need more.